# Centering a div over an image / container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've read a few different articles on this but just can't wrap my mind around it for some reason today.

In WordPress, I'll have an actual img tag (in a div container) and would love to overlay the post title and some of the excerpt text, centered over the image itself.

The tricky thing is... I won't know the height of the image unless I want to restrict the user and the post title length. Using css for a default and jQuery for enhanced styling is an option.

Here's a dummy example of the elements http://cl.ly/image/3X3t2t2g3h22

Fiddle of the html structure I'll probably shoot for... 
http://jsfiddle.net/4857G/

```
<div class="featured">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800x400" />
    <div class="overlay">
        <h1>Post Title!</h1>
        <p>Something else of variable length.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas or links appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="contain">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <div id="over"></div>
</div>
```

and css :

```
#contain {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
#over {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djedjex/q4LTr/1/

Answer (score 0):

This css will center the text horizontally but you still need a fixed top or bottom position.

http://jsfiddle.net/4857G/1/

```
.overlay{
   position: absolute; 
   top: 250px; 
   width: 100%; 
   text-align:center;
}:
```